# how to deserialize json array in asp.net core api in post method?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

how i can solve this problem (serialized/ and deserialize JSON array and store and read from sql server)?
thank you

i created asp.net core api that connected to angular project and occurs problem when i want post json that contains json array(ingredient) :

```
 { "RecepieName": "3222",
"Ingredient": [ { "ingredientName": "43243", "value": "33", "measure": "" },
{ "ingredientName": "565" , "value": "3", "measure": "" }],
"CookingTime": 3,
"Level": "advance", 
"ServingPerson": 3, 
"RecepieAbstration": "good food",
"RecepieText": "",
"CreateDate": "2021-01-04T12:37:51.948",
"ModifiedDate": "2021-01-04T12:37:51.948" }
```

when i use postman for test I encounter this error :

[postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkTTT.jpg)

you can see my model , dto and action post in controller :

Model :

```
  public class Recepie
    {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RecepieName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Ingredient { get; set; }   // include ingredientName / value / measure array
    [Required]
    public int CookingTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Level { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ServingPerson { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RecepieAbstration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RecepieText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NutritionalInformation { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
  
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

DTO : RecepieCreateDto

```
    public class RecepieCreateDto
{

    public string RecepieName { get; set; }

    //public int MentorID { get; set; }

    public string Ingredient { get; set; }


    public int CookingTime { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }

    public int ServingPerson { get; set; }

    public string RecepieAbstration { get; set; }

    public string RecepieText { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Action Post :

```
        //Post api/recepie
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult <RecepieReadDto> CreateRecepie(RecepieCreateDto recepieCreateDto)
    {
        var recepieModel = _mapper.Map<Recepie>(recepieCreateDto);
        _repository.CreateRecepieObject(recepieModel);
        _repository.SaveChange();
        var recepieReadDto = _mapper.Map<RecepieReadDto>(recepieModel);
        return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetRecepieByID), new { Id = recepieReadDto.ID }, recepieReadDto);
        // return Ok(recepieModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can implement solution like below code ;
1 : Create View model For input Api;

  

 public class RecepieCreateViewModel
        {
    
            public string RecepieName { get; set; }
    
            public List<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }
    
            public int CookingTime { get; set; }
    
            public string Level { get; set; }
    
            public int ServingPerson { get; set; }
    
            public string RecepieAbstration { get; set; }
    
            public string RecepieText { get; set; }
    
            public string NutritionalInformation { get; set; }
    
            public string Tags { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        }

   

 public class Ingredient
    {
        public string ingredientName { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string measure { get; set; }
    }


2 : Create Dto Model

public class RecepieCreateDto
{

    public string RecepieName { get; set; }

    public string Ingredient { get; set; }

    public int CookingTime { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }

    public int ServingPerson { get; set; }

    public string RecepieAbstration { get; set; }

    public string RecepieText { get; set; }

    public string NutritionalInformation { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

}

3 : Cast Ingredient Model ToJson Object In Api And Create New RecepieCreateDto Like Below Code

  var result=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recepieCreateDto.Ingredient);
        

   RecepieCreateDto readDto = new RecepieCreateDto
    {
        CookingTime = recepieCreateDto.CookingTime,
        Level = recepieCreateDto.Level ,
        ModifiedDate = recepieCreateDto.ModifiedDate ,
        NutritionalInformation = recepieCreateDto.NutritionalInformation ,
        RecepieAbstration = recepieCreateDto.RecepieAbstration ,
        RecepieName = recepieCreateDto.RecepieName ,
        RecepieText = recepieCreateDto.RecepieText ,
        ServingPerson = recepieCreateDto.ServingPerson ,
        CreateDate = recepieCreateDto.CreateDate ,
        Tags = recepieCreateDto.Tags ,
        Ingredient=result,

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing **array** for Ingredient but expecting **string**. Please change Ingredient to be `List<Ingredient>` where Ingredient is your new object which has name, value and messure. For example:

```html
 public class Ingredient
{
 [Key]
 int Id {get; set; }
 string IngredientName { get; set; }
 string Value { get; set; }
 string Measure { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE: please update the DTO model respectively and use it in **RecepieCreateDto**

```html
 public class IngredientDTO
 {
 string IngredientName { get; set; }
 string Value { get; set; }
 string Measure { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Please review the Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: i did your suggest but i occurs this error :  System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Ingredient' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Answer (score 0):

in RecepieCreateDto class Ingredient is a string but in your request json Ingredient is a array.
so change RecepieCreateDto class or request json.

```
"[{\"ingredientName\": \"43243\", \"value\": \"33\", \"measure\": \"\" },{ \"ingredientName\": \"565\" , \"value\": \"3\", \"measure\": \"\" }]"
```

OR

```
    public IList<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }
```

Comment: i did your suggest but i occurs this error : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Ingredient' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: In your DbContext class' OnModelCreating method, you do something like this:
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Ingredient>(builder =>
    {
        builder.HasNoKey();
    });

Comment: sorry , i did it and get new error :      'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Recepie.Ingredient' of type 'List<Ingredient>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class for Ingredient property.

```
public class Ingredient {
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } // This might be an int, you can change this on your purpose.
    public string Measure { get; set; } // This might be an int, you can change this on your purpose.
}
```

Looks like the ingredient you posting is a collection type so making Ingredient List<> or any other collection type might do it.

```
public class RecepieCreateDto
{

    public string RecepieName { get; set; }

    //public int MentorID { get; set; }

    public List<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }


    public int CookingTime { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }

    public int ServingPerson { get; set; }

    public string RecepieAbstration { get; set; }

    public string RecepieText { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

You might need to make similar changes to your Recepie model after these changes.

Comment: i did your suggest but i occurs this error : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Ingredient' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.